# open in a new window only works on the first TAB at webbowser

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, tabcontrol

I wrote this code to open links in a new TAB, If I right click on links and choose open in a new window, it's work!

**My problem is: If I am in the first TAB it's work, but in the second one dose not work.**

What should I add to make this code to the whole tabs? any hints?

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow1(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow
   e.Cancel = True

    Dim thiselement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement
    Dim Browser As New WebBrowser
    Dim targeturl As String = thiselement.GetAttribute("href")
    With Browser
        .Navigate(targeturl)
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    End With

    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(targeturl)
    TabControl1.SelectTab(int)
    TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser)
    AddHandler Browser.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading
    AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done
    int = int + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: The `int` variable seems pretty useless. Besides, it must be zero-based. You're better of using `TabControl1.SelectTab(TabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1)`.

Comment: If I remove/edit "int" I will have problems in my whole code

Comment: What does it do? I'm curious. - Well in my answer the only thing you would _need_ to copy is the last line before `End Sub`. In case you still want to use `int`.

Comment: Wait I will use your method "TabControl1.TabPages.Count" because I have other problems from "int"

Comment: Okay, whatever you'd like. I explained it a little in my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed to add a handler for the `NewWindow1` event:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_NewWindow1(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.NewWindow
    e.Cancel = True

    Dim thiselement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement
    Dim Browser As New WebBrowser
    Dim targeturl As String = thiselement.GetAttribute("href")
    With Browser
        .Navigate(targeturl)
        .Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    End With

    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(targeturl)
    TabControl1.SelectTab(TabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1)
    TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(Browser)
    AddHandler Browser.ProgressChanged, AddressOf Loading
    AddHandler Browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf Done

    'You missed this line.
    AddHandler Browser.NewWindow, AddressOf WebBrowser1_NewWindow1
End Sub
```

I also replaced the `int` variable with `TabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1` which selects the last tab (which is the new one) as the `int` variable may get changed during other events. So I'd recommend you to use `TabControl1.TabPages.Count` and `TabControl1.SelectedTab` (or maybe even `TabControl1.SelectedIndex`) for those kinds of methods.

Comment: You have made me confused with this ".Browser.NewWindow1" :D thanks to edit it with this "NewWindow" it's work now like a charm, Thanks a lot, I will remove "int" in my whole code it's seems make problems, awesome guy :)